# How to modify a liner regression in python 3.6?

Tags: python, statsmodels, patsy

The code looks like:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

df = pd.read_csv('reg_data.csv')
f = 'inf ~ rh*temp*tl*Tt*C(location)'   
lm = smf.ols(formula = f, data=df).fit()
```

But it always gives me an error:

```
numbers besides '0' and '1' are only allowed with **
```

The data in the file are all different numbers. Some have 2 decimals some have more.
Any idea to solve this problem and get regression summary? (by `lm.summary()`)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you found an interesting bug.

First, the error message isn't talking about the numbers in your data. That error message happens when you type a literal number into your formula, like in `"y ~ 3*x"` it will raise that error because it doesn't like the 3.

But your formula doesn't have any numbers in it, so what's going on? Well, you're hitting a bug in the formula parser: the way it checks if something is a number, is by checking if you can pass it to `int(...)` or `float(...)` and get a value back. But in Python, `float("inf")` is a valid expression that returns the floating point value representing infinity, even though plain `inf` alone isn't a number in Python.

I filed the bug here: https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/118

And the workaround for now is to avoid using the string `inf` as the name for one of your columns. (You should probably avoid `nan` too, for the same reason.) Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you very much! it's helpful!